# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0 using ant

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have just started with Ant. I want to append some data to the context-value tag.

Here is the XML

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/abc.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

and here is the ant build target

```
<target name="deploy">
    <!-- edit web.xml to update context-param-->
    <replaceregexp file="$web.xml" match='${web-app.context-param.param-value}' replace="${web-app.context-param.param-value},/WEB-INF/new.xml" />
</target>
```

but this is showing

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
${web-app.context-param.param-value}
^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3104)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2101)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1047)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpMatcher.getCompiledPattern(Jdk14RegexpMatcher.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpMatcher.matches(Jdk14RegexpMatcher.java:95)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.doReplace(ReplaceRegExp.java:336)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.replaceAndWrite(ReplaceRegExp.java:527)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.multilineReplace(ReplaceRegExp.java:522)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.doReplace(ReplaceRegExp.java:427)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.execute(ReplaceRegExp.java:487)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
```

How can I make this working and what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was missing to include xmlproperty for file web.xml.

```
<xmlproperty file="web.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
```

After adding the above line to my build.xml this works fine.